Perl script to find and replace attributes in an XML based on values from separate text file
I have cobbled together a Perl script that replaces a specific attribute of a specific tag into what I need it to be. The script is as follows...
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use utf8;
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)', ':std';

#ingest data
my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ->parsefile('test.xml');

#iterate all tags <host>
foreach my $host_id  ( $twig -> get_xpath('//host') ) {
   #check testname regex match
   if ( $host_id -> att('id') eq 'AAAA' ) {
       $host_id -> set_att('id', '1111');
   }
}

#iterate all tags <guest>
foreach my $guest_host  ( $twig -> get_xpath('//guest') ) {
   #check testname regex match
   if ( $guest_host -> att('host') eq 'AAAA' ) {
       $guest_host -> set_att('host', '1111');
   }
}

open ( my $output, ">", "new.xml" ) or die $!;
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented');
$twig -> print ( $output );


And here is the XML that I want to modify...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lodgings>
    <host id="AAAA">
        <display-name lang="en">Host1</display-name>
    </host>
    <host id="BBBB">
        <display-name lang="en">Host2</display-name>
    </host>
    <host id="CCCC">
        <display-name lang="en">Host3</display-name>
    </host>
    <guest start="20240720120000 +0000" stop="20240720140000 +0000" host="AAAA">
        <title lang="en">Title1</title>
    </guest>
    <guest start="20240720120000 +0000" stop="20240720140000 +0000" host="BBBB">
        <title lang="en">Title2</title>
    </guest>
    <guest start="20240720120000 +0000" stop="20240720140000 +0000" host="CCCC">
        <title lang="en">Title3</title>
    </guest>
</lodgings>

My problem now is that there are 100 or so "hosts" that I need to change and for ease of editing I would like to write a separate text file that has a record of the "hosts" that I want to change and what I want to change them to. Something like this...
hosts

    AAAA => 1111
    BBBB => 2222
    CCCC => 3333


How can I modify the script to reference a separate text file and check for each attribute and then replace them accordingly such that the XML looks like this...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lodgings>
    <host id="1111">
        <display-name lang="en">Host1</display-name>
    </host>
    <host id="2222">
        <display-name lang="en">Host2</display-name>
    </host>
    <host id="3333">
        <display-name lang="en">Host3</display-name>
    </host>
    <guest start="20240720120000 +0000" stop="20240720140000 +0000" host="1111">
        <title lang="en">Title1</title>
    </guest>
    <guest start="20240720120000 +0000" stop="20240720140000 +0000" host="2222">
        <title lang="en">Title2</title>
    </guest>
    <guest start="20240720120000 +0000" stop="20240720140000 +0000" host="3333">
        <title lang="en">Title3</title>
    </guest>
</lodgings>


I really don't even know where to start with this. When I googled it I couldn't find anything that I could understand that looked like it was what I needed.

== AAAA has two major flaws. First, == is numerical equality, it will cast a string to a number (0 in this case). You want eq for string equality. Second, AAAA is a bareword. It may be cast to a string when used as a string, but it will issue a warning. If you have run this code with warnings on, as you claim, you would know this. So, this is likely not the code you were running. Posting questions about code you are not actually running is bad form on stackoverflow.

How about XSLT for the task?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

Thank you very much for your feedback. I am very new to this. Please let me know if I have addressed what you have asked for and corrected my mistakes.

Just create a lookup table from the file.
my %host_mappings = (
   "AAAA" => "1111",
   "BBBB" => "2222",
   "CCCC" => "3333",
);

Then it's just a question of looking up the updated value.
my $new_host = $host_mappings{ $old_host } // $old_host;


Thank you. I don't quite understand how to integrate that into the script but at least I know that I need to read up on lookup tables.

You already showed you know how to extract the current host value ($old_host) and how to set the host value to a new value ($new_host).
